# intention for new group - but how solve data-floods?

Tags: accessibility, community, video-streaming

We are a group of deaf (in Germany and worldwide) people, who want to join together to one group, and they are interested in Ubuntu. Now point is: script-language, no deaf person is very fond of script-language and not every deaf person knows the oral script-language of international deaf people. So, it would be easier to communicate via video web-cam in sign-language.

The thing is then to store all questions in video-format because of sign-language
comprehensible for every deaf.

But then there is increasing data-flood for questions and answers. 
How do I  solve this with such a web-video-forum at Ubuntu ?

I found now

http://loco.ubuntu.com/

We would like to start there.

Comment: This seems like an interesting question. Can you explain more what you mean by script-language and how that might be used as an alternative to video? Is this a technical/IT support group? It is a little hard to tell what solution you are asking for. Thanks.

Comment: script-language, means your spoken English and how you write your spoken English - but deaf have different grammar in sign-language - it is not same like spoken English grammar (and not same like written). This different grammar in sign-language is same tricky thing for German and else languages. Therefore "visual-way" is easier for deaf people. And yes - there would be as well private interested persons as technical/IT ones like in world of hearings.

Answer (score 1):

solution would be this (thought about it over afternoon):

the deaf person, sends a video in sign-language with question to
translator. Translator writes video in English and posts this question
here on askbuntu.com

when answer is arriving - then translator sends answer in sign-language to deaf back.

this would work, and there would be no over-load of video-files at forum 
resp. at ubuntu.com

I myself am ready to edit and translate all incoming videos - this would mean
a good job for me !

Comment: hm tested one video for 1 minute in low resolution - would amount to 64 Megabytes. - pooh ! thats too much for e-mail traffic. so would be than a little special portal for deaf at ubuntu-forums or at askubuntu an idea - with live-cam. 1 question max. 3 to 5 minutes via web-cam. and the answer is sent as e-mail (not as video). this would shorten the suggested e-mail-traffic much more. this would mean a working-place similiar like an editor at newspapers. to do: translating, editing, recherche=investigating and research.